# MacOS Safari not loading webpages with internet connection

Tags: network, safari, wifi

After waking my macbook from sleep, sometimes Safari will not load any webpage - it starts loading and just gets stuck. Chrome, Whatsapp and other applications seem to work fine. After clearing DNS cache still nothing, but Chrome still works.

Checked - no proxies interfering. Switching to iPhones hotspot also does not work, still no connection. Switching wifi on and off - still nothing. Connecting via wifi, router works as on my other computer and iPhone internet works. The only way to resolve this is a full reboot of my mac, after which Safari starts working again like a charm.

Is there anything I could try to fix this issue without needing a full reboot every couple of days?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `softwareupdate -l`and if you see any update reading `Label: Safari ....`  Quit safari then run `softwareupdate -ia` and then try again.